# Return base type instead of derived type in a generic method

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

I have a `BaseClass` as follows

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string A { get; set;}
    public string B { get; set;}
}
```

and another class derives from the `BaseClass` as follows

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string C { get; set;}
}
```

I have a generic method which may return any derived class which inherits `BaseClass`.

```
public T MyMethod(bool returnBase) where T : BaseClass
{
    if(!returnBase)
    {
        T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(someString);
        return T;
    }
    else
    {
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass
        {
            A = "some string",
            B = "some other string"
        };
        return (T)bc;
    }
}
```

In this code, when `returnBase` is FALSE everything works OK, but when it is set to TRUE, I want to return `BaseClass`, but since I have defined the return type (T) as the `DerivedClass` in the calling code, I get Exception.

How can I get this code running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be an error in inheritance in the cast `(T)bc` since you can not cast the parent to the child. It is equivalent to saying `all Animals are Dogs` although there are other animals (e.g. Cats) as well, which are definitely not dogs.

In order to get it running, I would propose to implement the `else` in the following way:

```
T defaultObj = new T
{
   A = "some string",
   B = "some other string"
}

return defaultObj;
```

Since `T` is a child of `BaseClass`, it should have all properties from the base class.

Comment: That was something I have tried previously but it did not work because I forgot to type `where T : BaseClass, new()` instead of `where T : BaseClass`

Answer (score 2):

Just set the method return type as BaseClass and avoid the (T) casting when you return the base

```
public BaseClass MyMethod(bool returnBase) where T : BaseClass
{
    if(!returnBase)
    {
        T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(someString);
        return T;
    }
    else
    {
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass
        {
            A = "some string",
            B = "some other string"
        };
        return bc;
    }
}
```